# What is the difference between these healing perks?

Tags: genshin-impact

I am unsure what the differences are between these sets 2-piece healing bonus perks on artefact sets. They looks identical to me, just with different wording.

[image: Maiden's Distant Love vs Sea-Dyed Blossom]

> Character Healing Effectiveness +15%

> Healing Bonus +15%

What are different bonuses doing?

Comment: Don't know anything about the game, but *healing effectiveness* sounds like out going health (like healing an ally) while *healing bonus* sounds like your personal healing only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be exactly the same.

If you look at the artifact summary screen (don't mind the actual number, this is just a random screen I found on Google)

[image]

you should notice that in both cases the "Healing Bonus" parameter is increased by 15%. So this is just inconsistent wording.

Note that this is different from the 2p bonus on Traveling Doctor, which only increases the effect of received healing.